# My mouse scroll button changes volume instead of scrolling

Tags: audio, mouse, scrolling

Since yesterday, my mouse scroll button isnt working as it has to. Once i try to scroll down a page, my sound goes down, same with scrolling up->sound increases.

Other buttons also not working as intended.

Im on Windows 8.1 and using mouse MODECOM MC-GM1
Tried reinstalling drivers, restarting pC but without success.
Would be really nice if any of you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Yours faithfully, Svetozar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)? It is extremely versatile and allows you to remap your mouse keys (up to 5 of them plus what your scroll wheel does). I'll be happy to help you once you set it up if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue with the dpi button. Hold down the DPI button for 7 seconds and it reverts back to scrolling the page.

Answer (score 0):

Happens also to me time to time. Try plugging mouse into another USB port. Or if you use some usb hub try plugging the mouse directly into your computer. Or simply try restarting. Looks like some kind of bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).